# cascade change in style and show in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragraph that is set to hidden
`<td align="center" colspan="2" ><p id="p2" style="display:none">Invalid values</p></td>`

I am trying to set it to visible using show.I have the following line in my code 
`(document.getElementById("p2").show(2000);`but it is not doing anything
Edit:
I have the following scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean *add the show function to it* ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: If you have jQuery included, then you can do it like `$('#p2').show();` - BTW, added the jQuery tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments state above, use jQuery's `.show()` function: http://jsfiddle.net/bMWMT/1

```
$("#p2").show();
```